# Replacing all of a type of character in a string with another character

Tags: java, android, string

I'm trying to replace all of the |'s in a list with quotes, i have tried

```
 serverList.replaceAll("|", "\"");
```

but it doesn't seem to work, it doesn't change anything, am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Well, it works for me. Could you show us some of your code? Maybe an example of what `serverList` could be?

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that you misunderstand what `replaceAll` does.  It does not / cannot change the target string ... because strings are immutable.  But unless you show us what you wrote, we can only guess what your problem is.

Comment: serverList is String ArrayList ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `replaceAll()` expects a regex. The character `|` is a control character in regex. To make the regex parser understand that you "literally" mean `|`, you should pass `\|` to the regex parser. But `\` is a control character in Java. To make Java understand that you mean to pass `\|` to the regex parser, you should pass `\\|` as the first argument to the `replaceAll()` method.

Of course, you could also just use the `replace()` method, which does not interpret the first argument as regex: `serverList.replace("|", "\""")` (or `serverList.replace('|','"')` in this particular case) will return the desired string.